# How can I tag a user in a photo using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried:

```
$args = array(
  'access_token' => $access_token,
  'id' => $uid
);

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$idPhoto}/tags";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

It has returned me:

```
{"error":{"type":"QueryParseException","message":"Unknown path components: \/tags"}}
```

It does not seem possible because its not in the Facebook documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#publishing

Can someone confirm me that it's not possible to tag a user in a recently uploaded photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current mechanism to set tags with the Facebook Graph API.

You can use [photos.addTag](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.addTag) with the old REST API which you should be able to download here: http://pearhub.org/get/facebook-0.1.0.tgz. If anyone has a better link, I would appreciate it.

Looking at this article from the Facebook developers http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/371 it seems likely that the new API will never support setting tags "let the users do the tagging". This is unfortunate for apps (like mine) that want to integrate tagging.

Answer (score 28):

Uploading image and tagging multiple people in one step using PHP Facebook Graph API:

```
$args = array(
  'message' => 'Message',
  'image'   => '@' . realpath($path_to_image),
  'tags'    => array(
     array(
      'tag_uid'=> $friend1_uid,
      'x'      => $x1,
      'y'      => $y1,
     ),
     array(
      'tag_uid' => $friend2_uid,
      'x'       => $x2,
      'y'       => $y2,
     ),/*...*/
   ),
);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```

Where $facebook is initialized Facebook PHP SDK object. $data['id'] is id of uploaded photo.

Notes:
1. fileUpload option has to be set when initializing Facebook object:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  /*..*/
  'fileUpload'  => true,
));
```

2. [publish_stream permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) has to be granted;

Comment: Works! I'm curious, how did you figure out to use 'tag_uid'? The Photo doc page says to use 'to' (which works for a single tag) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/. They change things so fast their documentation can't keep up!

Comment: what are the y 'x' n 'y' for?

Comment: (x, y) is coordinates of tag in image you are uploading.

Comment: Can anyone help in uploading image and tagging friends in Android?  i can figure out that first upload the photo, then using the uploaded Id, tag the friends, but practically not sure

Comment: @Andrius Do you know what units are used for these coordinates?  Fraction of span of the image? Pixels? Measured from top or bottom and left or right?

Comment: @JohiasburgFrowell it was a while since I used this, but I would guess it's pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Change the url to

`$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$idPhoto}/photos";`

`tags` is not a compatible method! use `photo` to retrieve the specified data

Take a look at!

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo for tagging users in photos.

Comment: Sorry but in your link there is nothing about tagging someone.  I don't need to retrieve the data but to post it.