# Facebook C# SDK Upload Photos with Tagging data Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

How do i upload a photo with tagging info using graph api ?

the php solution i found is at http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=86152

```
$data = array(
                     'tag_uid' => $friend,
                     'x' => rand() % 100,
                     'y' => rand() % 100
                  );
$datatags[] = $data;
$attachment = array(
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'tags' => $datatags
          );
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$attachment['image'] ='@'.realpath($filename);
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$aid.'/photos', 'POST', $attachment);
```

just need to know the syntax to add multiple tags.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiple tags by passing array of tag arrays like in this example: [Uploading image and tagging multiple people in one step using PHP Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017861/how-can-i-tag-a-user-in-a-photo-using-the-facebook-graph-api/5476343#5476343)