# how to tag people in a facebook album via the graph API (php)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tag a user in a photo using the Facebook Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017861/how-can-i-tag-a-user-in-a-photo-using-the-facebook-graph-api)

As title says, how can i tag people via the Facebook graph API on an existing album?

Comment: i want to tag ppl in an album not in a photo

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question is about tagging individual photos, not albums. Perhaps the techniques are the same, but it warrants it's own discussion.

Comment: Not a dupe- this is about albums not posts

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished through the Facebook Graph API.

At Facebook's core is the social graph; people and the connections they have to everything they care about. The Graph API presents a simple, consistent view of the Facebook social graph, uniformly representing objects in the graph (e.g., people, photos, events, and pages) and the connections between them (e.g., friend relationships, shared content, and photo tags).

```
The connections supported for people and pages include:
Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=...
Photo Tags: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=...
Photo Albums: https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=...
Video Tags: https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos?access_token=...
```

Or use this

```
$args = array(
  'message' => 'Message',
  'image'   => '@' . realpath($path_to_image),
  'tags'    => array(
     array(
      'tag_uid'=> $friend1_uid,
      'x'      => $x1,
      'y'      => $y1,
     ),
     array(
      'tag_uid' => $friend2_uid,
      'x'       => $x2,
      'y'       => $y2,
     ),/*...*/
   ),
);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args);
```