# Tag an Album with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to use Facebooks graph API to tag people in an album? Note: I don't want to tag individual photos, but an album on the whole.

I have experimented with the [facebook Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and have found that the POST request to tag a facebook user in a photo does not work when you substitute the photo's id with an albums. It returned

```
{
  "error": {
  "message": "Unsupported post request.", 
  "type": "GraphMethodException", 
  "code": 100
}
```

}

**Please Note**: My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017861/how-can-i-tag-a-user-in-a-photo-using-the-facebook-graph-api) as my questions are about tagging **albums** NOT photos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no way to tag users in albums.
You can't do that in facebook as a normal user, as far as I'm aware, so why would it be possible via the api?
When you see users tagged in albums, it's just facebook aggregating the photo tags.

Also, if you look at the [Photo object documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo), you'll see that it has the [Tags connection](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags), on the other hand the [Album object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) does not have a similar connection.

Comment: Good point about it not being possible in the regular interface. Someone told me it was possible and I assumed they were right. Silly in hindsight! And the documentation refs cinch the deal. Thanks.